# Generate Angular2 forms from Swagger API specification

Tags: json, swagger, angular2-forms, jsonschema

I'm looking for a way to generate a set of Angular2 form templates from a Swagger API definition file. I want a result that will allow me to test my POST/PUT requests, and even use it in my app.

After some research I found this Angular2 form library that takes a JSON schema as input: https://github.com/makinacorpus/angular2-schema-form

So if you know of a Swagger -> JSON Schema converter that will work too.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> So if you know of a Swagger -> JSON Schema converter that will work
>   too.

Swagger 2.0 supports a subset of JSON schema draft 4. This is what swagger's *Schema* object is. From the [docs](http://swagger.io/specification/#schemaObject):

> The following properties are taken directly from the JSON Schema
>   definition and follow the same specifications:
>
> - $ref - As a JSON Reference
> - format (See Data Type Formats for further details)
> - title
> - description (GFM syntax can be used for rich text representation)
> - default (Unlike JSON Schema, the value MUST conform to the defined type for the Schema Object)
> - multipleOf
> - ...
>
> The following properties are taken from the JSON Schema definition but
>   their definitions were adjusted to the Swagger Specification.
>
> - items
> - allOf
> - properties
> - additionalProperties

It should be a fairly simple exercise to manually extract the schema from your swagger, but I don't know of any automated tool to do this. I think the fact some of the JSON schema properties have been modified by swagger may make auto conversion problematic in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenAPI Client Generator](https://github.com/zijianhuang/openapiclientgen) can generate typed forms codes of Angular Reactive Forms. In addition to its wiki, an article "[Generate Typed Forms of Angular Reactive Forms from Swagger / OpenAPI definitions](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5375552/Generate-Typed-Forms-of-Angular-Reactive-Forms-fro)" may walk you through.